# Are std Modules compatible with Precompiled Headers?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

If you create a new project with the `WinRT/C++ console application` template (i.e. precompiled headers), and change the language to `/std:c++latest` you get the following error

> 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\modules\std.ixx(147,1): fatal  error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?

which can be fixed by disabling std modules

> C/C++ -> Language -> Build ISO C++ Standard Library Modules -> No

### How can we get them to work together?

Same thing happens if we try cppwinrt modules (need to enable [scan-sources-for-module-dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/c-cpp-prop-page?view=msvc-170#scan-sources-for-module-dependencies))

```
import <winrt\winrt.ixx>;
```

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-C1010-with-VS-2022-version-1760-/10337222